# TypeError Cannot read property of undefined even with default values

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I am trying to use default values for when I delete a list from my todo list application, so that whenever it is trying to get the current list info it will use the default for a split second until the post request refreshes the available lists. I have tried every possible way of setting default values but I am still getting the TypeError EVEN when I am doing a console.log statement... This makes absolutely no sense because if I put "console.log(undefined)" right above it, this statement is fine and doesn't cause any errors obviously, but the next line will have console.log(myUndefinedStatement) and it will cause this error.
Here is my code. The comments are different options for the default values that I have all tried but none have worked. And some of them undefined is a string but I tried it both ways just because I couldn't think of anything else. Also for some of them the default value was a realistic thing, and other times it was "hi" because I wasn't sure if my other value was possibly undefined as well so I was trying something that was 100% not undefined.

```
function getCurrentListTitle() {
        // let title = (availableLists[clickedListIndex].title !== "undefined" ?availableLists[clickedListIndex].title : "Hi")
        // return title
        console.log(undefined)
        console.log(availableLists[clickedListIndex].title)
        if (Object.is(availableLists[clickedListIndex].title, undefined)) {
            console.log(availableLists[0].title)
            return availableLists[0].title
        } else {
            console.log(availableLists[clickedListIndex].title)
            return availableLists[clickedListIndex].title
        }
        // return Object.is(availableLists[clickedListIndex].title, undefined) ? console.log("was undefined") : console.log("wasn't undefined");
    }    // ? availableLists[0].title : availableLists[clickedListIndex].title;
```

Here is some more code that might be helpful for understanding my application

```
const [lists, setLists] = useState([])


    function deleteList (clickedEl) {
        console.log(lists)
        const delList = {
            name: "please delete",
            listId: clickedEl.id
        }
        if (clickedEl.id) {
            Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/todos/delete", delList)
            .then( () => setLists(delList));
        }
        console.log(lists)
    }

const [availableLists, setAvailableLists] = useState([{title: "", items: ["", "", ""]}]);
    
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        
        let isMounted = true;
        Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/todos/").then(response => {
          if (isMounted) setAvailableLists(response.data);
        })
        return () => { isMounted = false };
      }, [lists, items]);
```

UPDATE:
I was asked to show where my functions were being called or passed so here is my return statement. The function call is passed in the list element. You might notice there are other getCurrentList functions but I only included the one in the function because they basically all do the same thing just one for title, one for id, etc.

```
return(
<div>
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
        <Menu 
        onAdd={addList}
        onDelete={deleteList}
        onRename={renameList}
        onChange={changeCurrentList}
        availableLists= {availableLists}
        clickedListIndex= {clickedListIndex}
        />
        <List 
        title={getCurrentListTitle()}
        items={getCurrentListItems()}
        onItemAdd={addItem}
        onItemDelete={deleteItem}
        listId={getCurrentListId()}
        toggleDone={toggleDone}
        />
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
    )
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show the full interplay between functions and actions. Where do you call `getCurrentListTitle` and `deleteList`? Of course `console.log(indefined)` is OK, but if you try to read an object's property that is not defined is not.

Comment: If `availableLists[clickedListIndex].title` is throwing a TyperError, that means that `availableLists[clickedListIndex]` is undefined. You need to check for that.

Comment: Ok I updated the post to show where I call the functions. Also @terrymorse I understand it's undefined, as thats the error that is getting thrown at me, I am just asking if it is undefined, why isn't it letting my use the default values or console log it. Even if it is undefined it shouldn't throw an error when console logged.

Comment: Instead of `if (Object.is(availableLists[clickedListIndex].title, undefined))`, do `if (typeof availableLists[clickedListIndex] == 'undefined' || Object.is(availableLists[clickedListIndex].title, undefined))`. That will prevent the TypeError.

Comment: It seems from your comments that your problem occurs when there are no lists to be shown. Looking at the structure of the elements in your <div>s, in this case you just don't want the <list> element to be shown at all, so maybe you should hide that element until you get the refresh, rather than trying to show a "default" list.

Comment: Also, in your code, why is there a call to `setLists(delList)` in the callback for `Axios.post(...).then(..)`? What does that do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getCurrentListTitle() {
    
    if ( availableLists[clickedListIndex] ){
        console.log(availableLists[clickedListIndex].title)
        return availableLists[clickedListIndex].title
    } else if ( availableLists[0] ){
        console.log(availableLists[0].title)
        return availableLists[0].title
    };
    // EDIT after OP's comment
    // throw new Error( "No list was found" );
    console.log("No list found");
    return "No list found";
};
```

or maybe

```
function getCurrentListTitle() {
    let title = availableLists[clickedListIndex] ? availableLists[clickedListIndex].title
                : availabileLists[0] ? availableLists[0].title
                // EDIT after OP's comment
                // : null ;
                : "No list found" ;
    console.log( title );
    return title;
};
```

Comment: This had the same end result. It threw the error "no list was found". So my code is still not working :(

Comment: Hmmm - In your comments on your original question, you say you want to show the "default". But what is the "default"? I thought from your code that the default that you wanted to show was the element at index 0, but if that's not the case, then you need to return something else. So instead of throwing the error, you should return whatever is the default that you want to return - any empty string, perhaps. Or maybe a title that says "No list has been created".

Comment: Ok this worked, it just didn't end up being great for me because of how my application works, but as far as answering my question, you did help so thank you! I ended up being able to avoid all of this by just fixing the problem from the source and delayed the render instead of just trying to make defaults. Thanks again